# firebase cloud messaging data reading

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

We added firebase cloud messaging to our Flutter project. We do our real-time messaging here. I need to read firebase cloud messaging data. I could not find how to do information such as the number of messages sent. I would be glad if you help.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Delivery reports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#message-delivery-reports) are available in the Firebase console, and you can export the information to CSV from there.

There is also an [API to get aggregated delivery data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#aggregated_delivery_data_via_the_data_api). I'm not entirely sure whether this API can be accessed directly from the client though.

Finally, if the above don't work for your use-case, you can configure FCM to [export delivery data to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#bigquery-data-export) and then build your own reporting API on that.

Comment: thanks 
Frank van Puffelen